# access complex string data returned by curl

Tags: php, string, post, curl

I'm having trouble accessing the data that is being returned via curl. The data is returned as a complex string. I say complex because it uses curly braces and it looks like an array.

I tried to access the data like you would an array, eg. `$var['key']`, but that gave me an error:
`WARNING: Illegal string offset`

Here is what is returned via curl:

```
string(1422) "{"transactions":
[{"transaction_id":143720,"currency_adjustment":20,"offer_id":null,"offer_name":null,"description":"Cash Out","timestamp":"11\/19\/14"},
{"transaction_id":143718,"currency_adjustment":-10,"offer_id":null,"offer_name":null,"description":"Cash Out","timestamp":"11\/19\/14"},
{"transaction_id":143716,"currency_adjustment":-10,"offer_id":null,"offer_name":null,"description":"Cash Out","timestamp":"11\/19\/14"},
{"transaction_id":143672,"currency_adjustment":0.1,"offer_id":null,"offer_name":null,"description":"Referral Earnings","timestamp":"11\/19\/14"}]}"
```

I want to gain access of `currency_adjustment`.

I tried to do it like this:

`$response['currency_adjustment']` & `{$response['currency_adjustment']}`

**How can I access the data in this string?**

Comment: This string looks like JSON to me. You can use "json_decode" to convert the string to a PHP array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = (array)json_decode($response);
$data  = $result["transactions"];
echo $data[0]["currency_adjustment"];
```

Comment: worked with `$result = json_decode($response,true);`

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
$array = json_decode($your_string);
```

and also you might want to read more about JSON format:

http://www.json.org/